# Matrix & EE 2.9.2 SQL Error

Tags: channel-entries, matrix, pixelandtonic, file-uploads, sql

I am using version 2.9.2 EE and Matrix 2.6.1 (both the latest versions of each software). Each time I try to publish a channel entry that has a Matrix fieldtype I am getting the following error message. Can anyone assist me with why I am getting this error.

[image]

A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'is_draft' in 'where clause'

SELECT row_id, col_id_1, col_id_2, col_id_3, col_id_4, col_id_5 FROM exp_matrix_data WHERE field_id = 105 AND entry_id = 937 AND is_draft = 0 ORDER BY row_order ASC

Filename: third_party/matrix/ft.matrix.php

Line Number: 3044
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a database column that was added in Matrix version 2.5 for compatibility with Better Workflow. It sounds like you may have updated the files for that add-on but not triggered the update by visiting Add-Ons > Fieldtypes > Matrix to trigger Matrix’s update script.